# Use of "approximately"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Is *approximately* used correctly in the following sentence?

> Our congregation is comprised of approximately sixty to eighty different ethnic and cultural groups.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the phrase *sixty to eighty* necessarily implies that the figures are approximate, and that therefore the inclusion of the word *approximate* is superfluous (even if the actual figure may be marginally outside the limits.

On the other hand, you could say:

> Our congregation is comprised of *approximately seventy* different ethnic and cultural groups.

although, I would probably use the wording:

> Our congregation is comprised of *about seventy* different ethnic and cultural groups.

Answer (score 1):

If the speaker is allowing that there may be, say, 58 or 82, then yes.

If the speaker is instead trying to draw focus to his epistemic or pragmatic state, e.g., that it he is certain it is between sixty to eighty, but that he hasn't counted and he believes the exact number doesn't matter, then we're going in the direction of "hopefully" territory, which everybody seems to have a strong opinion about.

If you think hopefully is okay, then you should probably think this one is, too.

Answer (score 0):

> Our congregation **has between** sixty to eighty
>   different ethnic and cultural groups.

*Between* is used because you have given two different figures. If however, there are slightly fewer or more than eighty groups, you could rephrase the sentence this way;

> **We have estimated** that our congregation is comprised of **roughly** [*or approximately*] eighty
>   different ethnic and cultural groups.

By qualifying your statement with "we estimate" you are in effect saying you don't know *the exact number* of ethnic and cultural groups present in your congregation.